# What is the etiquette on voting for an answer which is a copy of another user's comment on the same question?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, etiquette, answers-as-comments

Today I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51690368/function-of-a-function-does-not-recognize-an-input-parameter) and one user (I'll call them UserA for differentiation) in the comments helped me get through my issue and gave me the answer to fix my issue, but it was left as a comment. A user (UserB) an hour or more later then just used UserA's comment as an answer with a extra fluff around UserA's comment.

My intuition says downvote since to me that is stealing.

Although I am aware that it could be seen as, UserB did not see the comment; they just happened to appear to be copying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Vote on the content

Is it a good answer? Upvote it.

Is it a bad answer? Downvote it.

In general, we should not be answering in the comments. But sometimes people don't have a lot of time and they leave a comment. If someone takes the time to collect that information into an answer, they have done a service.  They hopefully credited the commenter.  Also, some will mark the answer as community wiki, which means they will receive no reputation from the answer.

But, please don't downvote the content to punish someone.

([Related from MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288847/what-to-do-when-my-comment-has-been-reposted-as-an-answer-by-another-user))

Comment: Do you think it is acceptable to add a comment to UserB's answer asking them to give credit with the clause that if they did not see it they don't need to worry about it? Upvote it is then

Comment: You can always leave a polite comment, but I do not think there is much point.  If the commenter wanted credit, they should have left an answer.  And really, UserB would have only been crediting the commenter out of courtesy that they felt to the commenter. To try and tell someone to be courteous, can be a very tricky thing to do courteously.

Comment: @G.LC If you fell *really* strongly about it, then address a comment to UserA suggesting they post their own answer which you will then accept. If UserA declines/ignores the offer, then treat UserB's answer as if UserA had never posted any comments at all (just like this answer says to do).

Comment: @robinCTS Thats what I ended it up doing, good advice, thanks